# Cannot detect computer sleep in a service

Tags: c#, service

I wanna make a service that writes on a .txt file whenever you start or stop using your computer.
It can detect computer shutdown, but cannot detect sleeps or wake ups.

Here's the code I use:

```cs
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;
    CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
}
```

```cs
protected virtual bool OnPowerEvent(System.ServiceProcess.PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
{
    if (powerStatus == PowerBroadcastStatus.QuerySuspend || powerStatus == PowerBroadcastStatus.Suspend)
    {
        WriteToFile("computer turned off at : " + DateTime.Now);
        return false;
    }
    else if (powerStatus == PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeCritical || powerStatus == PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeSuspend || powerStatus == PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeAutomatic)
    {
        WriteToFile("computer turned on at : " + DateTime.Now);
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```cs
private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Mode)
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume:

            WriteToFile("computer turned on at : " + DateTime.Now);
            break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
            WriteToFile("computer turned off at : " + DateTime.Now);
            break;
    }
}
```

I'll be grateful for any help.

*note: WriteToFile is a custom method for writing to a .txt file*

Comment: Have you done anything about the prominent note in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?view=netframework-4.8): "This event is only raised if the message pump is running. In a Windows service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been started manually, this event will not be raised."

Comment: But how to start message pump in code? Is it possible?

Comment: yes I started a hidden form too but no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it working with help of `HiddenForm`. The changes which are required are:

**First:** Subscribe to `PowerModeChanged` even in say `HiddenForm_Load`

```
private void HiddenForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(OnPowerChange);
}
```

**Second:** Start Message pump using a thread as:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   //DO work needed in OnStart 

  // Message Pump will run in separate thread
  new Thread(ThreadWork.RunMessagePump).Start();
}

//Thread class to RunMessagePump
public class ThreadWork
{
    public static void RunMessagePump()
    {
        Application.Run(new HiddenForm());
    }
}
```

**Third:** Check tick box "Allow service to interact with desktop" in `Log On` tab of properties page.

Reference to example can be found at [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Where is that Log on tab?

Comment: Once you have installed your `Service` then select it in `Services` app. Right click and then select `Properties`. You see tables like `General`, `Log On`, `Recovery` etc.